# Ensure 2 choice fields on a record are not equal in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with 2 CharFields selected from nearly the same list of choices. They are the same except for the 2nd inclination having a "None" option.

```
class Pawn(models.Model):
    primary_inclination = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=PRIMARY_INCLINATION_CHOICES)
    secondary_inclination= models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SECONDARY_INCLINATION_CHOICES)
```

I want to ensure the same value can not be selected for both fields. For example, if my choices are selected from A, B, C, then A and B is fine, but A and A is not. It is ok for another Pawn to also have A and B.

Some things I've looked into:

- Specifying unique fields in Meta, but this makes the inclinations only selectable by 1 Pawn
- unique_together, no other pawn can have the same values for the two fields

Comment: How is this data getting into the model? Through an app/website? Can you enforce it on the page and confirm the values are not the same?

Comment: `unique_together` does not say the two fields are different. It says that no other pawn can have the values for the two fields.

Comment: @dfundako I have a form using CreateView that generates the object.

Comment: thank you willem, will edit to phrase correctly

Comment: @DavidJayBrady: what Django version do you use?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem 3.0.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **clean** method in your model to add custom validation and raise a ValidationError if the fields are the same:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class Pawn(models.Model):
    primary_inclination = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=PRIMARY_INCLINATION_CHOICES)
    secondary_inclination= models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=SECONDARY_INCLINATION_CHOICES)

    def clean(self):
        if self.primary_inclination == self.secondary_inclination:
            raise ValidationError('Primary and secondary inclinations should be different.')
```

Comment: A follow up question: is there a time I should validate in the view or form side versus writing validation code in the model?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. One example related to your question would be that you’d have 2 different views where you create the Pawn. And you want the validation only on one of the views. That’s when you can use View or Form validation

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea to validate as close to the source as possible. Implementing methods such as clean or save_model (within Django Admin) validates at the server level which is the last line of defense. You can also use JavaScript to keep your form's submit button disabled unless the selected inclinations are different. Another technique is to use form validation in the view:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django import forms

class PawnForm(forms.Form):
    primary_inclination = forms.CharField()
    secondary_inclination = forms.CharField()

    def clean(self):
        # Assume posted data includes pinc (primary_inclination) and sinc (secondary inclination)
        if 'pinc' in self.cleaned_data and 'sinc' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['pinc'] == self.cleaned_data['sinc']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    ("Primary and Secondary inclinations must be different"))
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                ("Both Primary and Secondary inclinations required")) 
        return self.cleaned_data
```

In your view you could have something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView


class PawnView(FormView):

    def get(self, request):
        context = {}
        context['form'] = PawnForm(request.POST or None)
        return render(request, 'pawn.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        context = {}
        form = PawnForm(request.POST or None)
        context['form'] = form
        if form.is_valid():
            # Form is valid...go ahead and process data
            new_pawn = Pawn.create(form.cleaned_data.get(‘pinc’), form.cleaned_data.get(‘sinc’)
            return redirect(reverse('pawn-view'))
        else:
            for k, v in form.errors.items():
                # Retrieve the text of our validation error or you can simply use form.errors
                context['error'] = v
            return render(request, 'pawn.html', context)
```

You can show the validation error in pawn.html very easily:

```html
<div class="pawn-error">
    <h3>{{ error | striptags }}</h3>
</div>
```